# How can I make a userform complete another one?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform, with two comboboxes. One of them contain Part numbers, the other one contains the part descriptions like:

Part number:
01982391823

Description:
5/8" Festo valve

Both of them have the items from another sheet (database).

What I want do to is, if I put the code in the code combobox, the other one shows me the corresponding description, and vice versa (because they are about 400 items). Is that possible?

EDIT:

With the help from "Love Coding" and with the adaptations, I inserted your code:

```
'from here starts the macro test, to see if it can search the code by text and vice versa

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range
Set WS = Planilha3

If ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
    'LOOP THRU ALL THE DATABASE AND LOOK FOR THE DESC ROW NUMBER AND GET THE PART
        For a = 2 To WS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If CStr(WS.Range("C" & a).Value) = ComboBox2.Value Then
            ComboBox3.Value = WS.Range("B" & a).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
End If


End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range
Set WS = Planilha3

If ComboBox3.Value <> "" Then
    'LOOP THRU ALL THE DATABASE AND LOOK FOR THE PART ROW NUMBER AND GET THE DESC
    For a = 2 To WS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If CStr(WS.Range("B" & a).Value) = ComboBox3.Value Then
            ComboBox2.Value = WS.Range("C" & a).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
End If
'daqui fecha a primeira parte do código que procura de acordo com a descrição, ele continua no "initialize"
'from here ends the macro test, to see if it can search the text by code and vice versa
End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'trecho para ir para selecionar a ultima linha em branco da tabela
    Dim linha As Integer
    linha = Planilha1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1


'colando as informações do formulário no banco

    'data
    Planilha1.Range("A" & linha) = TextBox1.Text
    'código
    Planilha1.Range("B" & linha) = ComboBox2.Text
    'item (descrição)
    Planilha1.Range("C" & linha) = ComboBox3.Text
    'quantidade
    Planilha1.Range("D" & linha) = TextBox4.Text * (-1)
    'usuário
    Planilha1.Range("U" & linha) = ComboBox1.Text



End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

'botão cancelar (nunca colocar ponto entre unload e me)
Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

'permitindo apenas 10 caracteres (2 da data, 2 do mes, 4 do ano, 2 barras)
TextBox1.MaxLength = 10

'condição pra depois do dia e do mês ele escrever a barra automático
    If Len(TextBox1) = 2 Or Len(TextBox1) = 5 Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "/"
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

'proibir colocação de caractere fora numeros
    If KeyAscii < Asc(0) Or KeyAscii > Asc(9) Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_Change()



End Sub

Private Sub TextBox4_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)

'proibir colocação de caractere fora números
    If KeyAscii < Asc(0) Or KeyAscii > Asc(9) Then
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'campo usuário

'colocando itens a serem exibidos no combobox "usuário"
'private sub Userform_initialize ()
'ComboBox.AddItem "item a ser adicionado"
ComboBox1.AddItem "DEMETRIUS RABELO"
ComboBox1.AddItem "ERIC SANTOS"
ComboBox1.AddItem "GERALDO GUIMARÃES"
ComboBox1.AddItem "REGINALDO SILVA"

    'campo código
    'puxando os códigos existentes na planilha
    'ComboBox2.List = Planilha3.Range("B:B").Value

'campo código

'apenas mostrando valores não vazios no campo código
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range
Set WS = Planilha3

'deixando a planilha vazia
WS.Visible = False

With WS
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each aCell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If aCell.Value <> "" Then
            Me.ComboBox2.AddItem aCell.Value
        End If
    Next
End With

'campo item

With WS
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each aCell In .Range("C2:C" & LastRow)
        If aCell.Value <> "" Then
            Me.ComboBox3.AddItem aCell.Value
        End If
    Next
End With

' continuation:

'ADD ITEMS TO COMBOBOX PART
With ComboBox2
    'Loop thru all the parts and add to the combobox part
    For a = 2 To WS.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ComboBox2.AddItem WS.Range("B" & a).Value
    Next a
End With


'ADD ITEMS TO COMBOBOX DESCRIPTION
With ComboBox3
'Loop thru all the description and add to the combobox description
    For b = 2 To WS.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ComboBox3.AddItem WS.Range("C" & b).Value
    Next b
End With

End Sub
```

I've added the Dim part in the beginning already, to avoid "error 424" in the macro, however I'm not being able to do what I want yet

[Ive added an image to clarify. From portuguese, "CÓDIGO" is the combobox 2, the code space. "ITEM" is the description (combobox3).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YoCc.png)

Comment: Post code *in your question* - it's unreadable in a comment

Comment: thanks for the advice! I've corrected :)

Comment: You will get 424 if you use (eg) `WS` without first setting it to a worksheet object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've fixed it. Settled WS as worksheet in the beginning of the code. It solved the error, however the code still not working. I'm gonna try to put a form's screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, I assumed that your part number is located in column A and description at column B.

ComboBox Part Name: cbo_part, 
ComboBox Desc Name: cbo_desc

```
Dim mySh As Worksheet


Private Sub cbo_desc_Change()

If cbo_desc.Value <> "" Then
    'LOOP THRU ALL THE DATABASE AND LOOK FOR THE DESC ROW NUMBER AND GET THE PART
    For a = 2 To mySh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If CStr(mySh.Range("B" & a).Value) = cbo_desc.Value Then
            cbo_part.Value = mySh.Range("A" & a).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
End If
End Sub

Private Sub cbo_part_Change()

If cbo_part.Value <> "" Then
    'LOOP THRU ALL THE DATABASE AND LOOK FOR THE PART ROW NUMBER AND GET THE DESC
    For a = 2 To mySh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If CStr(mySh.Range("A" & a).Value) = cbo_part.Value Then
            cbo_desc.Value = mySh.Range("B" & a).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next a
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set mySh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'name of your worksheet database

'ADD ITEMS TO COMBOBOX PART
With cbo_part
    'Loop thru all the parts and add to the combobox part
    For a = 2 To mySh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        cbo_part.AddItem mySh.Range("A" & a).Value
    Next a
End With


'ADD ITEMS TO COMBOBOX DESCRIPTION
With cbo_desc
'Loop thru all the description and add to the combobox description
    For b = 2 To mySh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        cbo_desc.AddItem mySh.Range("B" & b).Value
    Next b
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What a big code! Hahaha thanks, I would not be able to do that with my experience right now! I'm testing it right now and will post more info!

Comment: I've tested the code, it helped a lot! I've edited the question with the error that I'm getting, with the info of the informations that I've changed in the code.

Comment: Do I Have to put a button from make the code work? I've tried but with no success